# What is a boolean string? I was solving one question which said given a "BOOLEAN STRING", the DIVIDE(i, j) function returns a k

Tags: algorithm

I am not sure if I understood what is a "Boolena string"
Heres the complete question:
Given a Boolean string, the DIVIDE(i, j) function returns a k such that k = i−1, if all the values
between i and j is TRUE, else the number of TRUE values between i and k is equal to the
number of FALSE values between k + 1 to j. (a) Implement a linear time algorithm for the
DIVIDE function. (b) UPDATE(i, b, k) returns an appropriate value of k, if the ith value is
changed to b. Implement a constant time algorithm

Comment: Example for "Boolean string"s:
`"car AND (red OR blue) OR motorcycle"`.
Perhaps:
`"vehicle=='car' AND (color=='red' OR color=='blue') OR vehicle=='motorcycle`"`

Comment: It sounds like they're using "string" to mean "array".

Comment: I agree with interjay, sounds like input is an array of TRUE or FALSE values, or some related format (e.g. a string of '0' or '1')

Comment: Okay, thank you all.

Comment: Any idea about how to solve this question?